# py2app Mach-O header on Mac

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, anaconda, py2app

I have created a wxpython GUI application on macOS Sierra 10.12.5. I am trying to use py2app to create a standalone App. My python installation:

```
Python 2.7.13 (Anaconda intel python, virtual environment).
py2app 0.14
```

Here is my setup python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
$ python build_CtAnnotator.py - script for building CtAnnotator

Usage:
    % python build_CtAnnotator.py py2app
"""
from setuptools import setup
import sys
# from distutils.core import setup

sys.setrecursionlimit(20000)

APP = ['CtAnnotator.py']
OPTIONS = {'site_packages': True,
           'argv_emulation': True,
           'alias': False,
           'plist': {'PyRuntimeLocations': ['/opt/anaconda2/envs/intelpython2/lib/libpython2.7.dylib']}
          }

setup(app=APP,
      options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
      setup_requires=['py2app'],
     )
```

Here is the error I get after many, many lines of py2app output.

```
WARNING: Mach-O header in '/Volumes/<...>/Repository/CtAnnotation/dist/CtAnnotator.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/numba/_dispatcher.so' may be too large to relocate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build_CtAnnotator.py", line 24, in <module>
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
  File "/opt/anaconda2/envs/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/opt/anaconda2/envs/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/envs/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/opt/anaconda2/envs/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 825, in run
    self._run()
  File "/opt/anaconda2/envs/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1040, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/opt/anaconda2/envs/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1152, in run_normal
    self.create_binaries(py_files, pkgdirs, extensions, loader_files)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/envs/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1512, in create_binaries
    platfiles = mm.run()
  File "/opt/anaconda2/envs/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachOStandalone.py", line 146, in run
    node.write(f)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/envs/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachO.py", line 133, in write
    header.write(f)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/envs/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachO.py", line 343, in write
    self.synchronize_size()
  File "/opt/anaconda2/envs/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachO.py", line 333, in synchronize_size
    self.parent.filename, self.total_size + self.sizediff, self.low_offset, self.sizediff))
  ValueError: New Mach-O header is too large to relocate in '/Volumes/<...>/Repository/CtAnnotation/dist/CtAnnotator.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/numba/_dispatcher.so' (new size=1752L, max size=1744L, delta=24L)
```

@Adrian K remarked ([py2app Mach-O header error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957806/py2app-mach-o-header-error)) that this could be solved by downgrading scipy to 0.14.0. Besides this not being an accepted answer, downgrading scipy is incompatible with the intelpython core version of my installation. (Indeed my python configuration differs from that of the previous OP in this important respect.) Any recommendations or other solutions?